# GraphicsDevice - can't return from fullscreen

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, fullscreen

I'm currently trying to make a full-screen window in Java running in Linux. The thing is I can actually make the JFrame full-screen but if the frame is set undecorated it can't return to the original window again. If the windows is decorated I'm able to return to the original size.

```
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    ...
    f.setUndecorated(true);//If set Window can't return to original size
    gs.setFullScreenWindow(f);

    gs.setFullScreenWindow(null);//Doesn't work!
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
changeFrameFullScreenMode(Frame app){
  GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment
   .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
  if (gd.getFullScreenWindow() == null){
    app.dispose();
    app.setUndecorated(true);
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(app);
    app.setVisible(true);
  }else{ // back to windowed mode
    app.dispose();
    app.setUndecorated(false);
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    app.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reliably change an undecorated, full-screen frame back to windowed mode.  I suggest creating two `JFrame`s, one full-screen and the other windowed.  When you want to return to windowed mode, add the content pane to the windowed frame (this automatically removes it from the full-screen frame) e.g.

```
windowedFrame.setContentPane(fullScreenFrame.getContentPane());
windowedFrame.pack();
windowedFrame.setVisible(true);
fullScreenFrame.dispose();
```

Comment: This is a good idea but with a small problem. I'm using VLCJ and returning to a windowed frame makes the video go black! No image  whatsoever.

Comment: @mundu, I have seen that when trying to make a `JDialog` full-screen, but it's always worked ok for me with a `JFrame`.

Comment: i'm currently using a JFrame and a Canvas to paint the video frames. They're synced with the following command.

`mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(factory.newVideoSurface(canvas));`